# EntityFramework : The specified cast from a materialized 'System.String' type to the 'System.DateTime' type is not valid

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, dbcontext

I have a SP which I am executing with help of `SqlQuery` method of `DbContext.Database`. I am calling it as follows:

**EDIT 1:- passing `DateTime` now**

```
var t = form["datetime"];//value is 2013-May-08 09:30
DateTime dtm;
if (!DateTime.TryParse(t, out dtm))//successfully parses
     dtm = new DateTime(2013, 05, 8, 9, 30, 0);
var rTime= new SqlParameter("@rTime", dtm);
var result = UoW.ExecuteSp<SPResult>("spResult @rTime", rTime).ToList();
```

The last line throws the exception that specified cast from `string` to `DateTime` is not valid.

Following is the definition of SP.

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[spResult]
(
    @rTime SMALLDATETIME --VARCHAR(32)
)
AS
BEGIN
--OTHER CODE
END
```

If I directly execute the SP in SQL Management Studio it runs without any problem:

```
EXEC spResult ='2013-May-08 09:30'
```

<strike>In SP the string is converted to date time as follows:</strike>

```
@resultAt SMALLDATETIME = CAST(@rTime AS SMALLDATETIME)
```

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Is the input parameter to the stored procedure a string?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all! So if your stored procedure expects a `SMALLDATETIME` - why isn't the parameter already of that type??

Comment: @marc_s I was passing `DateTime` object at first but that was not giving right results :'(

Comment: But then you should find out *why* it was giving you the wrong results - just changing it to a string is the worst possible approach....

Answer (score 2):

What does `spResult` take as a parameter? Presumably it is a `datetime`? In which case: *give it a `DateTime`*:

```
var t = DateTime.Now;
```

or

```
var t = new DateTime(2013,5,8,9,30,0); // 8 May 2013, 9:30am
```

If the error relates to `SPResult` - well, we can't see that so it is hard to comment: but again - map SQL `[n][var]char(len|max)` to C# `string`, and map SQL `datetime` to C# `DateTime`.

Comment: Changed to `DateTime` again but still in limbo